# How to generate Client GraphQL queries from .graphql files via com.graphql-java

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am investigating GraphQL with java using :-

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-java-tools
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.2.4'
```

I have multiple `.graphql` files that define my different types and one `.graphql` file defines my queries.

I have developed the folloiwng code to merge all my .graphql files and instantiate an executable schema

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    final List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    Files.list(Paths.get("schemas")).filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".graphql")).forEach(paths::add);

    wire(paths);

}

private static void wire(final List<Path> paths) {

    final SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();
    final SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();

    final TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new TypeDefinitionRegistry();
    for (final Path path : paths) {
        typeRegistry.merge(schemaParser.parse(path.toFile()));
    }

    final RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
    final GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);

    final GraphQLObjectType queries = graphQLSchema.getQueryType();
    final ObjectTypeDefinition objectTypeDefinition = queries.getDefinition();

}

private static RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring().wiringFactory(new EchoingWiringFactory()).build();
}
```

What wish to achieve is to generate the actual GraphQL query text string such as this :-

```
{
   "operationName":"testQuery",
   "variables":{
      "filters":"",
      "unread":false,
      "offset":20,
      "limit":20
   },
   "query":"query testQuery($filters: String, $unread: Boolean, $source: String, $sourceId: ID, $offset: Int, $limit: Int) {\n  testQuery(keywordFilter: $filters, unreadFilter: $unread, sourceFilter: $source, sourceIdFilter: $sourceId, offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {\n    info {\n      totalCount\n      __typename\n    }\n    contents {\n      uuid\n      bookmarked\n      removed\n      title\n      authors {\n        first_name\n        last_name\n        __typename\n      }\n      uuid\n      abstract\n      doi\n      year\n      issue\n      volume\n      pages\n      journal_name\n      publisher\n      new\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

Is this possible using `graphql-java-tools`?

Using this code I can see my queries are contained in the executable schema object

```
    final GraphQLObjectType queries = graphQLSchema.getQueryType();
    final ObjectTypeDefinition objectTypeDefinition = queries.getDefinition();

    System.out.println("queries.getDefinition() = " + objectTypeDefinition);
    System.out.println("queries.getFieldDefinitions() = " + queries.getFieldDefinitions());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `graphql-java` and `graphql-java-tools` are both server-side libraries. For constructing client-side queries, you need a client library like `apollo-android` (despite the name, it works with all Java/Kotlin, not just Android).

Comment: @DanielRearden I can see they are server side, however surely they "know" the full query details? Shouldn't they be capable of generating the query statements?